# How to fetch objects from CoreData using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am using CoreData to store some entities. I have some entities in CoreData and want to fetch them using `NSPredicate`. I am using the following code but the returned `objectsArray` is empty. Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];  
NSManagedObjectContext *context = delegate.managedObjectContext;  
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Devices"];  
NSError *error;  

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"deviceName == %@",  deviceNameString];  
[request setPredicate:predicate];  
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Devices" inManagedObjectContext: context]];  

NSArray *objectsArray = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Comment: Is error non-nil after `executeFetchRequest::`?

Comment: the error is nil and the array has zero objects

Comment: If you remove the predicate do you have objects in the array ? If yes, the error is from the predicate, if no, then your saving method is not working

Comment: when i remove the predicate, i get all objects in the Devices entity. but when i put predicate then i get zero objects

Comment: Did you check if those objects have the correct deviceName set when you're retrieving them from the database ?
Also, try a predicate like this : "deviceName LIKE [c] %@"